# source tree unable to push

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

my source tree not able to push suddenly, not knowing why even I've updated the source tree and git is still same. does anyone met this problem before

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --set-upstream origin 20181122_online_booking_uat:20181122_online_booking_uat
```

Pushing to https://souce@bitbucket.org/souce/souce.git

```
fatal: unable to access https://souce@bitbucket.org/souce/souce.git/': error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
Completed with errors, see above.
```

Answer (score 4):

I've fixed it by update the Git in Tools > Options > Git > Update Embedded, after run all the things just click ok

Comment: Bumped into the same problem just today as well, and this worked for me too, thanks for updating

Answer (score 2):

I see you've solved your issue, but for people for whom this doesn't work: make sure you use the latest version of Sourcetree.
Bitbucket has disabled support for TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 since December 1st 2018, which affects older versions of Sourcetree.

https://bitbucket.org/blog/deprecating-tlsv1-tlsv1-1-2018-12-01

You can update by going to Tools -> Updates